# Update the AccountUser Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

Is it possible to modify or update the AccountUser Object using the ClientID and ClientSecret credentials or do I need to use an API User that is set-up in the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ClientID and ClientSecret.  You need to get the token first, then put as your soap header:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">TOKENGOESHERE</fueloauth>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Good luck!

Comment: @victorcorey - i would suggest updating your question or opening a new instead of adding comments. Helps others find answers the are looking for :)